# Getting thread id in c++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I am following course on YouTube
where I saw this line of code:

```
uint32_t threadID = std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id());
```

Why are there curly braces in between hash type and `thread::getid()`? Also I've seen that it can be replaced by `()`. What's that about?

Comment: To clarify a bit, `threadID` is the wrong name for that variable. It should be `hashed_thread_id`, or something of that sort. It's not a thread id. And while I'm picking on the code, the return type of `std::hash::operator()` is `std::size_t`, which is not necessarily a `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) is a [struct](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash), not a function.  The code initializes a temporary/anonymous hash object, then calls the hash object's [`operator()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash/operator()) with the calling thread's ID as an argument.

Therefore, that code is equivalent to this:

```
std::hash<std::thread::id> myHashObject{};
uint32_t threadID = myHashObject(std::this_thread::get_id());
```

The curly-braces are just the new-style way to initialize a C++ object.

Answer (score 1):

`std::hash` is a type. We need an object of that type to do actual hashing. So, the `{}` (or `()`) is creating a temporary object of that type. Then the parentheses containing the `std::this_thread::get_id()` means we're invoking the `operator()` on that object.